# JNA: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/path/libname.so': not found in resource path

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, jna

I've got a bit controversial error message:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library
> '/libpath/libname.so': Native library (libpath/libname.so) not found in
> resource path ([..., file:/libpath/libname.so, ...])

```
Native.loadLibrary("/libpath/libname.so", LibInterface.class)
```

My classpath includes `/libpath/libname.so`. Also, I tried to specify the library's folder and all it's dependencies' folders in `jna.library.path`, `jna.platform.library.path`, `java.library.path` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with no success.

## Debug JNA log

```
Looking for library '/libpath/libname.so'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: /home/jofsey/build/install/lib:/usr/local/lib:/libpath
Trying /libpath/libname.so
Adding system paths: [/home/jofsey/build/install/lib, /usr/local/lib, /libpath]
Trying /libpath/libname.so
Looking for version variants
Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc for /libpath/libname.so
```

Comment: Are you running on an 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?

Comment: Try with just Native.loadLibrary("libname", LibInterface.class). If you are building a JAR then you may need to catch the exception and try extracting the lib from the JAR in such case.

Comment: @cubrr 64-bit JVM

Comment: What message does it give you if you just add the library's directory path to jna's path env var and load `name` (without the lib prefix or .so extension)? Remember that jna will concatenate the platform specific prefix.

Comment: @cubrr `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'name': Native library (linux-x86-64/libname.so) not found in resource path ([..., file:/libpath/libname.so, ...])` with the following options `-Djna.library.path=/lib_dependency_folder:/libpath` and `-Djna.platform.library.path=/lib_dependency_folder:/libpath`

Comment: @kvr `Native.loadLibrary("libname", LibInterface.class)` causes the following error `Unable to load library 'libname': Native library (linux-x86-64/liblibname.so)`. My `libname.so` is not packed inside a JAR, but my class-files are.

Comment: Try putting it inside the a directory named `linux-x86-64/` inside the resource path.

Comment: @cubrr `Unable to load library 'name': Native library (linux-x86-64/libname.so) not found in resource path ([..., file:/libpath/linux-x86-64/libname.so, ...])`

Comment: Gah, how frustrating. Can you reproduce this with some public scared library with which we could try?

Comment: @cubrr I've got the same error with `/usr/lib/libc-2.17.so`: `Unable to load library 'libc-2.17.so': Native library (linux-x86-64/libc-2.17.so) not found in resource path (..., file:/usr/lib/libc-2.17.so, ...])`

Comment: @Jofsey ok thanks, can you check if your JVM is 64-bit? Check the output of following command: java -d64 -version. Also in my earlier comment I should have said the library name without the lib prefix and extension, like cubrr mentioned, but sounds like you already tried that too.

Comment: @kvr `java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)`

Comment: Check the mount permissions on /tmp We had an issue where /tmp was mounted with the -noexec flag which kept us from using native libraries. Use -Djna.tmpdir= to set a directory that the Java process can write to and allows executables.

Comment: What does `ldd <your library>` say?

Comment: @JimW eh, still the same error, but it was a good guess. My `/tmp` is a regular folder inside `/` which is mounted without `-noexec` - `findmnt / / xfs rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota`. So when I tested `-Djna.tmpdir=/my_new_tmp_path_with_777_rights` nothinght has changed.

Comment: Have you sure that your lib and jvm program are running at the same processor architecture? In other words are your lib compiled in x64 and your java program running in a x64 machine?